# Accidentally erased APFS partition while resizing Windows Bootcamp disk

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, apfs

This is my first post here. I recently wanted to add some more space to my windows' partition so I shrunk Mac HD by 60GB and rebooted.

I then used windows to join the unallocated space with its partition but something went wrong! I restarted the system and noticed that the Boot Manager was no longer able to find Mac HD, which makes me think the partition table has been accidentally overwitten.

Mac HD is running Mojave, APFS while Win HD is running Windows 10, NTFS.

So I tried to boot in recovery mode (Online version since it can no longer boot from the old recovery partition) and diskutil was showing 840GB of unallocated space (Mac HD).

I'm pretty sure the data is still there, can you help me restore the table?

Comment: how did you `shrunk`

Comment: I used disk utility

Comment: I have the exact same problem – how did you access you data? Or did you manage to rebuild the APFS container to run again?

Comment: I restored the APFS container copying the exact same container ID from one of my friend's computer with my same configuration. That turns out to be very dangerous but if you do it carefully you can get your data back as I did.